# Pure Virtual Method Called Error Google Protocol Buffer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, runtime-error, protocol-buffers

Right now I have a `QList` of protobuf Messages.  Inside of a while loop, I create messages and add them to the `QList`. I try to use the `DebugString` Method to print them out and in the while loop it works fine with no errors.  When I try to call the exact same `->DebugString()` method outside of the while loop I get:

> Abort (Core dumped).
>
> pure virtual method called terminate called without an active
>   exception

```
QList<const ::google::protobuf::Message*> allMessages;

while() {
    msgs::sensor::Plot nextMsg;
    ....
    allMessages.append(&nextMsg);
    std::cout << allMessages.at(0)->DebugString();
}
std::cout << allMessages.at(0)->DebugString();
```

Comment: You are adding dangling pointers to the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nextMsg` is a local variable inside the while loop, it will be destroyed when get out of the loop, and then address saved in `allMessages` becomes dangled. Any dereference on it is just UB.

If you want to use the pointers outside of the loop, you need to `new` them inside the loop (and `delete` them at last), or use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) to avoid manual memory management.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to new and delete them?

Comment: @Mike Such as `while() { msgs::sensor::Plot* nextMsg = new msgs::sensor::Plot; .... allMessages.append(nextMsg); ... }` and `while() { delete allMessages.at(i); }`

Comment: Works great.  Thanks!

Comment: @songyuanyao Hey I had to change my code for other reason and I now use:  
::google::protobuf::Message* curMessage;
msgs::sensor::Plot plotMsg;
curMessage = &plotMsg; and      'allMessages.append(curMessage);  how to I add a new and delete to this?

Comment: @Mike Yes, nothing changed essentially. The pointer appended to `allMessages` is still a local variable's address.

Comment: Ok so Is       ::google::protobuf::Message** curMessage = new ::google::protobuf::Message*;      corrret?

Comment: @Mike I think it should be `::google::protobuf::Message* curMessage = new msgs::sensor::Plot;`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115858/discussion-between-mike-and-songyuanyao).